# How can I speed a Selenium scraper on the New York Times dining website?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, runtime

Currently, I'm trying to scrape the New York Times dining website (nytimes.com/reviews/dining) and get a list of links and neighborhoods for each restaurant. Unfortunately, I've been running the codeblock below for about 9 hours on Google Colab, and the iterator X is on its 1,175th run. I'm trying to figure out what's going on, but I'm too scared to halt the cell and start over again. Is it the nested for loop that is causing this process to take such a long time?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options = chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/reviews/dining")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable
                                ((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Show More']"))).click()
url_list = []
nyt_dining = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Restaurant', 'URL', 'servesCuisine', 'priceRange', 'addressLocality'])

x = 0 
while(True):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located
                                             ((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.css-102xbk1")))
    url_before = len(url_list)
    for e in elements:
      # 2.1 Getting the links
      link = e.find_element_by_css_selector("a.css-gg4vpm")
      link = link.get_attribute("href") ##

      # 2.1 Getting the restaurant name
      name = e.find_element_by_css_selector("h2.css-8aqwnr")
      name = name.text ##

      # 2.3 Getting other information
      info = e.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.css-o4kdzz")
      info = info.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
      cuisine = ''
      price = ''
      neighborhood = ''
      for i in info:
        attribute = i.get_attribute("itemprop")
        if attribute == "servesCuisine":
          cuisine = i.text
        elif attribute == "priceRange":
          price = i.text
        elif attribute == "addressLocality":
          neighborhood = i.text

      # 2.4 Append to dataframe
      if link in url_list:
        continue
      else:
        url_list.append(link)
        nyt_dining = nyt_dining.append({'Restaurant': name, 'URL': link,
                                        'servesCuisine': cuisine,
                                        'priceRange': price,
                                        'addressLocality': neighborhood}, 
                                       ignore_index = True)
        print(x)
        x += 1
    url_after = len(url_list)
    if url_before >= url_after:
      break
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located
                                             ((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Show More']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    time.sleep(2)

nyt_dining
```

Comment: parallel execution

Comment: You can use Multiprocessing or Asyncio in Python, also better to check nytimes.com/robots.txt

Comment: Would running this code on Google Colab also be a contributing factor to why this is so slow?

Comment: Use `BeautifulSoup` along with `selenium`. They both together work fast as hell, and will satisfy your scraping needs. I used to scrape Wikipedia with selenium only, but it takes a hell of 2-3 minutes in scraping just a page, then I used both of these together and it does the job in under 10 seconds.